# Where can I find detailed info about the NIC in my MacBook Pro?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, network-adapter

Where can I find detailed info about the NIC in my MBP (6,2 - mid 2010)? The built-in "System Information" won't give anything more than the name (Airport extreme) and the MAC address. I'm running Lion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there something specific you want to know?

There is a `Show More Information` menu item in the `File` menu of System Information.
At least on my iMac this displays connection information, Firmware version and a lot of other stuff.

For the Airport specific stuff, you can try the following on the command line:

```
system_profiler -detailLevel full SPAirPortDataType
```

Comment: Thanks, that cmd is very useful. I was looking for the chipset, which strangely is printed out as firmware by `system_profiler`. Worse yet, it only says `Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0`, whereas I was interested in the full name (i.e. I need to know the last two digits).

Comment: Maybe this [iFixit Teardown](http://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/MacBook-Pro-15-Inch-Unibody-Mid-2010-Teardown/2212/1#s11324) for the MBP 15" helps. There is an [image of the Airport Extreme card](http://guide-images.ifixit.net/igi/HHJmWYjIcCWMcJvP.huge). Says "BCM943224PCIEBT" on there.

Comment: Yep, that's the one. Shame there's no other way than to physically open the macbook to check this. Many thanks nonetheless!